For US/UK merchants, Integrating Google Pay API with website and accept payments via QR Code/UPI
We are trying to implement Google Pay API integration for commerce websites belonging to US/UK merchants and there requirement is to accept payments via QR Code (similar to UPI payment gateway in India).
Can you please answer my following questions:

With Google Pay API website integration, is there a way to accept payments from customers via QR Code or any non-card payment method for US/UK merchants/websites?

Is the UPI payment gateway an India specific payment method?

Is there a similar alternative (globally available) method we can use for US/UK merchants?


We implemented Google Pay API tutorial and are able to select and verify credit cards from customers for payment but this alone does not fulfil our requirement because we need to accept payments when customer scans a QR Code we display on our website.
You help is greatly appreciated. Thanks you.
